# How to calculate difference between two timestamp columns depending on value of third column?

Tags: r, dataframe, timestamp

I have a dataframe:

```
col1                                      col2               col3
2019-04-26 12:37:11.52000      2019-04-27 12:37:11.52000          2
2019-04-28 12:37:11.52000      2019-04-30 12:37:11.52000          1
2019-05-03 12:37:11.52000      2019-05-08 12:37:11.52000          2
NA                             2019-05-08 12:37:11.52000          2
```

I want to create new column as difference of col2 and col1. Im going to use difftime function. However, I want there be values only if in that row value in col3 is 2. Otherwise it must be NA. So, desired result is:

```
col1                                      col2                  col3    diff
2019-04-26 12:37:11.52000      2019-04-27 12:37:11.52000          2      1
2019-04-28 12:37:11.52000      2019-04-30 12:37:11.52000          1      NA
2019-05-03 12:37:11.52000      2019-05-08 12:37:11.52000          2      5
NA                             2019-05-08 12:37:11.52000          2      NA
```

How to do that? How to add that condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may initialise the result column with `NA` and take difference of only those values that have `col3 == 2`.

```
df$diff <- NA
inds <- df$col3 == 2
df$diff[inds] <- as.numeric(difftime(df$col2[inds], df$col1[inds], "days"))
```

In a `dplyr` pipe you can use -

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(diff = if_else(col3 == 2, as.numeric(difftime(col2, col1, 'days')), NA_real_))
```

Comment: wow, cool solution. and is it possible to do it in a pipeline?

Comment: and why ```NA_real_``` and not just ```NA```?

Comment: `if_else` from `dplyr` is type-strict meaning it needs both the output in if and else of same type. `NA` is logical (`class(NA)`) whereas `NA_real` is numeric (`class(NA_real_)`).

Answer (score 0):

You could use dplyr.

```
dfnew <- df%>%
          mutate(diff = NA)%>%
          filter(col3 == "2")%>%
          mutate(diff = difftime(col2,col1, units = "auto"))
```